# How do I move members from board to organisation in Trello?

Tags: trello-organization, trello-boards

Is there a way to move all members from one board to a organisation this board is in?

Members are currently only members of the board and not of the organisation.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do is add the members to the organization using the 'Add Members' button on the Members tab from the organization's page.

Click on the org name link in the top left corner of any board to open the organization page.  Since the members are part of a board already, it should be easy to enter the member names.

Notes.
If there is no Organization name in the top left of the board, then the board is not part of an Organization